# How to let VS Code skip source files with no changes since last compiling?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

Eclipse CDT can automatically compile all the changed source files (if there are) in the project directory and link them. However the default "C/C++: g++.exe build active file" task would always compile the file even there was no change since last compile. Yes, it could be done by make file. Besides that, do VSC or its extensions provide some easier way to do so?

Here is how my tasks.json looks like:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "\"${config:task.gccpath}/g++.exe\"",
        "args": [
            "-Wall",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Debug/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${config:task.gccpath}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: ${config:task.gccpath}/g++.exe"
    }
]
}
```

And here is how my launch.json looks like

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Debug/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/IO/${relativeFileDirname}/",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "${config:task.gccpath}/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: No a build tool like Make or CMake, .... is the way to go to build a multi file C++ project

Comment: @rioV8 How about just one file in the project? When I click F5 to debug, can I set VSC to call g++ only when needed?

Comment: then you have to split compiling and debugging in `launch.json` and `task.json` and not connect them with the `preLaunchTask`

Comment: I'm surprised that VSC doesn't enable task.json to check if the source file modified before calling the command. It is a very basic feature, isn't it?

Comment: VSC is an Editor not an IDE. Tasks in Sublime also don't have checks. Tasks can do anything not only compile.